# HP pavilion keyboard driver is missing

Tags: windows-10, laptop, drivers, keyboard, hp-pavilion

My friend has an old [HP Pavilion g6-1a52nr Notebook PC](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC-series/5048672/model/5078477), 64 bit, the laptop's keyboard driver went missing after updating windows 10, the keyboard no longer works.

Windows updater can't find it, we tried several driver downloaders like Dumo and driver booster and easy drivers and HP support assistant and Snappy Driver, nothing works, the driver isn't listed on HP drivers list, they only list the touchpad driver.

How to reinstall it?

[image]

Comment: What does device manager show for the keyboards?

Comment: @Moab Please see the photo in the question, I just added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We did two things to fix the problem and I'm not sure which one of these things fixed it, nor I'm sure if this is the right way to fix it nor how long it will stay fixed.

- Installed the driver using Snappy Driver, but the computer didn't detect it
- Reset the bios by shutting it down and removing the battery and pressing the power button for 15 seconds, after the reset, the keyboard worked